# How many ways can you generate an error converting varchar to numeric that won't be caught by ISNUMERIC()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in the process of loading a bunch of tables into SQL Server and converting them from `varchar` to specific data types (`int`, `date`, etc.).  One frustration is how many different ways there are to break the conversion from string to numeric (int, decimal, etc) and that there is not an easy diagnostic tool to find the offending rows (besides `ISNUMERIC()` which doesn't work all the time).

Here is my list of ways to break the conversion that won't get caught by `ISNUMERIC()`.

- The string contains scientific notation (ie 3.55E-10)
- The string contains a blank ('')
- The string contains a non-alphanumeric symbol ('$', '-', ',')

Here's what I'm currently using to compensate:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN [MyColumn] IN ('','-') THEN NULL    -- deals with blanks
       WHEN [MyColumn] LIKE '%E%' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(20, 4), CONVERT(FLOAT(53), [MyColumn]))            -- deals with scientific notation
       ELSE CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE([MyColumn] , '$', ''), '-', '') AS DECIMAL(20, 4)) 
    END [MyColumn]             -- deals with special characters
FROM 
    MyTable
```

Does anyone else have others?  Or good ways to diagnose?

Comment: IsNumeric is the worst named function ever. It should be something more like CanBeConvertedToSomeDatatypeThatIsRoughlyResemblingANumber. But that is too long so they shortened it. See this article about why it "doesn't work". http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Comment: Also, consider adding one copied column and cleaning it step by step. Remove dollar sign, clean up scientific notation and so on. After that use try_cast and check the results. Doing this in one case statement could get ugly. What is science is combined with special characters?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use ISNUMERIC(). If you are on 2012+ then you could use TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT.

If you are on older versions, you could use some syntax like this:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM #TableA
    WHERE ColA NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST` all the way, Your SQL would work for integers, but as soon as you throw a decimal in there (`'1.0'`) it'll give a false answer.

Comment: Agreed, you probably want to expand the range of allowed characters slightly for `decimal` rather than `int` (allow `-`, `,` and `.`) as well, and a couple more checks to ensure only one `-`, only one `.`, `-` is at the start, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The problem with allowing `.`,`','`, etc is that that means the `CASE` would return TRUE (just like `ISNUMERIC` does). However, none of those character can be converted: `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(2,1),C) FROM (VALUES('.'),(','),('-')) V(C);` This is exactly why `ISNUMERIC` is an awful function.

Comment: @Larnu - I said expand the range. Your previous comment included an example *containing* `.` and so if we want to accept *your* example we need at least `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%`. But as I also indicated, we need further checks to ensure precisely one `.` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `LIKE '%[0-9]%'` instead of `ISNUMERIC()`

```
SELECT col, CASE WHEN col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' and col<>''
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
             END
FROM T
```

Comment: if you put a character in there this fails unfortunatly

Comment: `LIKE '%[0-9]%'` tells you it contains at least one digit. That's not the check you need. Usually you want the double negative to assert that it *doesn't* contain any *non-digit*s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT LIKE` to exclude anything that isn't a digit... and `REPLACE` for commas and periods. Naturally, you can add other nested `REPLACE` functions for values you want to accept.

```
declare @var varchar(64) = '55,5646'
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN replace(replace(@var,'.',''),',','') NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
    END
```

This allows you to accept decimals for your decimal / numeric / float conversions.

Comment: What about crazy things like an IP address when there might be more than one period. Not saying this is wrong but it could return false positives.